# SQL query error #1064 without any obvious error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm scratching my head over this error. I'm trying to import a sql file through phpmyadmin and it comes up with this errors one after another and I cannot sea anything wrong with it. Can someone please analyse the lines below and let me know if they see any errors?

Thank you

---

```
--
-- Table structure for table `jos_address_members`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_address_members` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `adid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `publish` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ordering` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '9',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 12
```

Comment: `NOT NULL DEFAULT '9',` ... remove the dangling comma.

Comment: As you can see, the error message identified the exact point at which the query went wrong, so next time you'll know where to look!

Comment: The bigger problem is the missing PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma after `DEFAULT '9'`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_address_members` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `adid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `publish` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ordering` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '9'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: ok. will consider it next time

Comment: Here, have an upvote...I couldn't even see it until I tried running the statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thats my error #1 - i do the same thing pretty often, when i do a lot of copy&paste

Comment: Thank you. It resolved the error for that particular line. Now I have to go through 9K lines of code to find other errors. Wish me luck!